# Toggle start and stop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm pretty new to this jquery/javascript stuff but i have this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AKgZn/2/).
So far i have it starting on click but it needs to stop on click as well and return to original state (#pause_button1) which needs to toggle. 
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but this could help:

```
var timer;
var imageNumber = 0;

$('#pause_button1').click(function() {
    startWorking(); 
});

$('#pause_button').click(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = false;
        $('#pause_button').removeClass('pause_button' + imageNumber);
        imageNumber = 0;
    }      
    else {
        startWorking();
    }
});

function startWorking() {
    function changeImage(element) {
        $('#pause_button').removeClass('pause_button' + imageNumber);
        imageNumber++;

        if (imageNumber > 6) {
            imageNumber = 1;
        }
        console.log(imageNumber);
        element.addClass('pause_button' + imageNumber, 200);        
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            changeImage(element)
        }, 200);
    }

    changeImage($('#pause_button'));
}
```

Comment: sorry that's basically it what you have done, but when stopped it needs to return to the first div (white block with green outline). thanks for your help :)

Comment: note that you should not use `attr('class', 'class-name')`, which I also corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a interval and use the `id` it returns to cancel it using `clearInterval`: http://jsfiddle.net/AKgZn/32/.

```
/* need to run this when clicked - need a toggle */

function changeImage(element, imageNumber) {
    function do_it() {
        imageNumber++;

        if (imageNumber > 6) {
            imageNumber = 1;
        }
        console.log(imageNumber);
        element.addClass('pause_button' + imageNumber, 200);

        element.attr('class', 'pause_button' + imageNumber);
    }

    return setInterval(do_it, 200); // execute every 200 ms,
                                    // return interval id
}

var intervalid;
$('div').click(function() {
    if(intervalid != null) { // interval running, cancel it
        clearInterval(intervalid); // clear the interval
        intervalid = null;
    } else { // start interval
        var id = changeImage($('#pause_button'), 0);
        intervalid = id;
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry that's basically it what you have done, but when stopped it needs to return to the first div (white block with green outline)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//...

var timeoutId = setTimeout(...);
element.data('timeout', timeoutId);

//...

var elem = $('#pause_button');
if(elem.data('timeout')) {
    clearTimeout(elem.data('timeout'));
    elem.removeData('timeout');
} else {
    changeImage($('#pause_button'), 0);
}
```